# Get the value from a datagrid row using jquery on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net, datagrid

I have the following datagrid.

It has only one column and many rows:

```
<asp:DataGrid id="grid1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
   <Columns>
     <asp:BoundColumn DataField="something">
       <ItemStyle CssClass="myclass"></ItemStyle>
     </asp:BoundColumn>
   </Columns>
/>
```

Note the **myclass** class in itemstyle.

When I click over a row I want to get the value in the row populated by the datasource.

I have the following jquery script:

```
$('.myclass').click(function () {
    // I DO NO KNOW WHAT TO ADD HERE ???
});
```

I've tried many solutions: `$(this).text, $(this).val, $(this).attr('text')`but with no success.

Comment: Can you update with the code that the ASP datagrid prints out? It could be that .myclass appears more than once...

Comment: AlexRichards it does appear only once, anyway @Chandra got right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try `$(this).text();` instead of `$(this).text` ?

Comment: Also the case with val, use `$(this).val();`

Comment: In this case, $(this).text() is the correct call to get the text. I just wanted to mention that $(this).val() is correct when trying to get the value, not $(this).val